How to test links in a JSON file?
I have a database in JSON containing multiple links and I cannot find a library to crawl it for valid and invalid links. I want to test each URL inside to look for broken links.
Property example:
{
      "Organisation": "British Association for Sexual Health and HIV",
      "Abréviation": "BASHH",
      "Spécialité": "infectiologie",
      "Type": "societe savante",
      "Actualités": "https://www.bashh.org/news/news/",
      "RSS": "No",
      "Publications ouvertes": "https://www.bashh.org/guidelines",
      "Publications RSS": "No",
      "Social": "https://x.com/BASHH_UK"
    },


Use any standard http client.

I had to build a script thanks to Codestral. Works on any JSON layout.
You need NodeJS 16+.
import axios from 'axios'
import fs from 'fs/promises'

// Find all links
function isUrl(str) {
  const urlPattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?' + // protocol
    '((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|' + // domain name
    '((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))' + // OR ip (v4) address
    '(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*' + // port and path
    '(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?' + // query string
    '(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$', 'i'); // fragment locator
  return !!urlPattern.test(str);
}

// Test links
async function testUrl(url) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    // console.log(`${url} is working. Statut : ${response.status}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`${url} is down. Erreur : ${error.message}`);
  }
}

// Look for links in JSON
function traverse(obj) {
  for (let key in obj) {
    if (obj[key] !== null && typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
      traverse(obj[key]);
    } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'string' && isUrl(obj[key])) {
      testUrl(obj[key]);
    }
  }
}

// Read JSON and test links
async function main() {
// Set JSON file location
  try {
    const data = await fs.readFile('../static/data/societes-savantes.json', 'utf8');
    const jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    traverse(jsonData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Erreur lors de la lecture du fichier JSON : ${error.message}`);
  }
}

main()

